# sys admin cannot log as some users

Tags: login, logging, grant-login-access

I have sys admin profile. I dont understand why I am not able to log as some users which have the same custom profile.
For example in the image, "Analyst T.O" has the same profile as "Analyst, Credit" and "Dorado William" but I the link "Login" does not exit.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about Chatter Expert, you cannot do that. 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_faq_administering_chatty.htm&type=5

Comment: Also You cannot login as deactivated user

Comment: You may like to refer [Log In as Another User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=logging_in_as_another_user.htm&type=5)

Comment: Ok understood with chatter Expert user. But what about Analyst credit, or William. They are users created which have the same profil and are active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found the answer.

The reason for which "login" link is not available in some users, is because those users have not granted access permmission to the admin.

Those users must go to: My settings/Grant Account Login Access and select Access duration for Your Company's Administrator.

[image]

After that you will be able to see "Login as " link:

[image]